# Removing NewLines After Certain BBCodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first question here, and I really want someone to help me!

I have created a Live BBCode to HTML convertor in jQuery & Javascript, It works like you type bbcode inside a textarea and it gets converted to html below, so people can see what they actually typing.

The things works great, but I have problem with newlines, for example, if **I type this BBcode:**

```
[b]askamn[/b]

[hr]
[hr]

[list]
[*]a
[*]b
[*]c
[/list]
```

**The output is:**

```
<strong>askamn</strong>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

**But I want it like this:**

```
<strong>askamn</strong>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<ul>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c<br></li>
</ul>
```

So you see two extra `<br>` appear after `<hr>`, this is happening because I press enter two times, **I want it to ignore this just upto 2 times.**

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code that you're using to parse newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a style-related question than anything. Depending on which browsers you're [wanting to support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) you can just use CSS's [Adjacent Sibling Combinator selector (`E + F`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```css
hr + br,
hr + br + br {
    display: none;
}
```

This selects any `br` element immediately following a `hr` element, and any `br` element following that.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/7ka6w881/).

Comment: Thank you mate. You saved my day.. I never even thought of that.. I believe this should also work classes and ids? like .amn + hr {displaY:none;}

Comment: @user1591869 yes it does. Happy to help. :)

Comment: Well, it does not seem to work on ul + br, I want to eliminate the <br> just after <ul>

Comment: @user1591869 it looks okay to me: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/7ka6w881/1/. Remember that most browsers give `ul` elements a top and bottom margin. If you want to remove this, you can specify `ul { margin-bottom: 0; }`